# ValidationAttribute dentro de un SfGrid, llega solo un valor de la fila con Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

Tengo en una clase un campo el cual, nunca debe de superar otro dentro de ella misma.

En ese campo le he creado una validación

```
        [CustomValidation]
        public decimal? CantidadTarea { get; set; } //(decimal(18,10), null)
```

Y en el método, compruebo que cuando llegue el value, nunca supere el valor con el que comparo

```
    public class CustomValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var Res = false;
            if ((decimal?)value != null)
            {
                var qtt = (validationContext.ObjectInstance as PartidaStock).CantidadStock;
                if ((decimal)value > (validationContext.ObjectInstance as PartidaStock).CantidadStock)
                {
                    return ValidationResult.Success;
                }
            }
            return new ValidationResult("Cantidad excedida de stock");
        }
    }
```

El problema llega dentro del SfGrid, primero muestro el encabezado del Editform:

```
    <EditForm EditContext="@EC" OnValidSubmit="@Submit">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
```

Y aquí muestro el contenido del SfGrid

```
<SfGrid @ref="GridInsumos" AllowPaging="true" DataSource="@LPartidasGrid" ShowColumnChooser="true" Toolbar="@(new List<string>() { "Add","Edit","Delete","Update","Cancel" })" style="min-height:80px;">
    <GridEvents OnActionBegin="OnActionBegin" OnActionComplete="OnActionComplete" TValue="PartidaStock"></GridEvents>
    <GridEditSettings AllowEditing="true" AllowDeleting="true" AllowAdding="true" Mode="@EditMode.Normal"></GridEditSettings>
    <GridColumns>
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(PartidaStock.Partida) HeaderText="Trazabilidad" EditType="EditType.DropDownEdit" Width="150" IsPrimaryKey="true">
            <EditTemplate Context="Partida">
                <SfDropDownList ID="Trazabilidad" Placeholder="Trazabilidad" TItem="PartidaStock" TValue="string" @bind-Value="@((Partida as PartidaStock).Partida)" DataSource="@LPartidasInsumos" AllowFiltering="true" FilterType="Syncfusion.Blazor.DropDowns.FilterType.Contains">
                    <DropDownListFieldSettings Text="Partida" Value="SelectorInsumo"></DropDownListFieldSettings>
                    <DropDownListEvents ValueChange="OnChangePartida" TItem="PartidaStock" TValue="string"></DropDownListEvents>
                </SfDropDownList>
            </EditTemplate>
        </GridColumn>
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(PartidaStock.CantidadStock) HeaderText="Stock" Width="200">
            <EditTemplate Context="detalleStock">
                @{
                    //Insumo = (detalleInsumo as PartidaStock).DescArticulo;
                    <SfNumericTextBox @ref="TxtBoxStock" ID="Stock" @bind-Value="@((detalleStock as PartidaStock).CantidadStock)" ></SfNumericTextBox>
                }
            </EditTemplate>
        </GridColumn>
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(PartidaStock.DescArticulo) HeaderText="Insumo" Width="200">
            <EditTemplate Context="detalleInsumo"> 
                @{
                    //Insumo = (detalleInsumo as PartidaStock).DescArticulo;
                    <SfTextBox @ref="TxtBox" ID="Insumo" @bind-Value="@((detalleInsumo as PartidaStock).DescArticulo)" ></SfTextBox>
                }
            </EditTemplate>
        </GridColumn>
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(PartidaStock.CantidadTarea) HeaderText="Cantidad" Format="N2" Width="200">
            <EditTemplate Context="detalleCantidad">
                @{
                    //Qtt = (detalleCantidad as PartidaStock).CantidadTarea;
                    <SfNumericTextBox TValue="decimal?" @ref="TxtBoxQtt" ID="Cantidad" @bind-Value="@((detalleCantidad as PartidaStock).CantidadTarea)"></SfNumericTextBox>
                }
            </EditTemplate>
        </GridColumn>
    </GridColumns>
</SfGrid>
```

En el momento de que se añade una nueva fila, y se edita el primer campo, se dispara el método OnChangePartida, el cual rellena las diferentes celdas

```
  public async void OnChangePartida(Syncfusion.Blazor.DropDowns.ChangeEventArgs<string, PartidaStock> args)
  {
      //Partida = args.ItemData.Partida;
      //TxtBox.Value = args.ItemData.CodigoArticulo + " " + args.ItemData.DescArticulo + " (Stock Disponible:" + Math.Round((decimal)args.ItemData.CantidadStock,2) + ")";
      //Insumo = TxtBox.Value;
      //TxtBoxStock.Value = args.ItemData.CantidadStock;
      //GUIDPartidaStock = args.ItemData.GUIDPartidaStock;
      //TxtBox.FocusAsync();
      //TxtBoxStock.FocusIn();
      //this.StateHasChanged();
      //PartidaStock p = new PartidaStock();
      //p.Partida = Partida;
      //p.DescArticulo = args.ItemData.CodigoArticulo + " " + args.ItemData.DescArticulo + " (Stock Disponible:" + Math.Round((decimal)args.ItemData.CantidadStock, 2) + ")";
      //p.CantidadStock = args.ItemData.CantidadStock;
      //p.GUIDPartidaStock = args.ItemData.GUIDPartidaStock;


      await GridInsumos.SetRowDataAsync(args.ItemData.Partida, args.ItemData);


      //TxtBox.ValueChange.InvokeAsync();
      //TxtBoxStock.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync();
      //GridInsumos.PreventRender(true);
      this.StateHasChanged();
      GridInsumos.CallStateHasChanged();

  }
```

El problema es que si lo escribo a mano sin disparar el evento y poniendo los datos por detrás, no hay problema.

Pero en el momento que lo hago en el evento, aunque les haga focus, solo me llega a la clase el valor que introduzco a mano.

He comentado los otros intentos.

¿De qué forma correcta cambio los campos de la row en creación para que los pueda capturar en la clase?

Gracias por vuestro tiempo!